# Property 'then' is missing' Error when calling angular resolve

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular resolver to get data before template get load. But I am getting an error.
Here is my resolver code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';

import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot,ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceResolve implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private apiservices: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    let JsonVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('RegistrationSteps'));
    let postData = {
      'token': JsonVal.auth_token
    }
    let url = 'getUserDetails';
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.apiservices.getUserDetailsByToken(postData,url));

  }
}
```

Here is my service code:

```
 getUserDetailsByToken(data,url){
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.post(this.base_url+url,data).map(ret=>ret.json());
  }
```

Here is how I am trying to get data in component:

```
let userData = this.route.snapshot.data['userdata'];
console.log(userData,'sssss');
```

here is how my route look like:

```
{path:'signup',component:VendorRegistrationComponent,resolve:{userdata:ServiceResolve}},
```

This is the error I am getting:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PromiseLike'.
  Property 'then' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Comment: Can you indicate the source line where you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because this

```
return this.http.post(this.base_url+url,data).map(ret=>ret.json());
```

Will return Observable, but you are trying to read as Promise `Observable.fromPromise(...)`, so, just change it to `return this.apiservices.getUserDetailsByToken(postData,url);` and everything will be ok.

Comment: It works. Thanks man.
I have a question If I want to use promises in the same code what change I have to made in above code?

Comment: @Rahul Just try this - `return this.apiservices.getUserDetailsByToken(postData,url).toPromise()` :)